# Edit forwarded MIME messages with mutt

Tags: mutt

Both forwarding complete MIME messages (mime_forward=yes), and editing a message's text when forwarding it (mime_forward=yes) is quite simple with mutt, but including the attachments **and** editing the message's text at the same time is not. I came across multiple suggestions:

1. Use ESC e (resend message) to use the original message as a template [link](http://www.shallowsky.com/blog/linux/mutt-fwd-attachments.html): This does not work, because mutt decodes the message body, turning non-ASCII characters into unpleasant strings.
2. Forward the original message as an attachment and edit its body using m from the attachments menu [link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=340405): This does not work, because there is "No mailcap edit entry for message/rfc822" (and even if there was such an entry – I do not want to edit the complete MIME message, but only its first part).
3. Bounce the original message: This requires editing the From header and manually quoting the original content, which takes too much time.

Is there any simple method to achieve most other mail clients' default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is through point 2 which you name. Mutt stores attachments in /tmp/ while the message is opened before sending.

1. Select the attachment part you wish to edit, in this case the part with type "message/rfc822"
2. Press Enter, the attachment is displayed within Mutt
3. Copy the path to the attachment from the bottom of the screen
4. Open the link in an editor such as vim
5. Make and save changes